# Get Customer ID in Magento mail template

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to display the customer ID in the emails that Magento send when a logged in customer places a new order.

I read that the next line should work, but it doesn't: {{var customer.ID}}.

I read a lot of forums but I can't find the answer. Any help is very much appreciated!

I got it working (with thanks to Nadir!) withn the following example:

```
<h1>Hallo {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}} (klant-ID: {{var customer.ID}}),</h1>
```

Comment: what about `{{var order.getCustomerId()}}`?

Comment: please put full html template

Comment: @AmitBera: Just place the code from Nadir in the mailtemplate where ever you need it to be.

Comment: @NadirSampaoli please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `customer` object is not injected in the *new order email template*.
You can instead get the customer id from the `order` variable:

```
{{var order.getCustomerId()}}
```